# Measure fps of Android Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

In `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener` callback, I just use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` to calculate the frame interval to get the fps, and it prints out this:

```
fps = 27.777779
fps = 34.482758
fps = 27.777779
fps = 32.258064
fps = 14.285714
fps = 35.714287
fps = 30.30303
fps = 17.54386
fps = 125.0
```

So my question is, is it true that the actual fps just fluctuates like that? If so, is there any reliable way to fix the frame rate, let's say I just need it to deliver at 15 or 20fps. Is it achievable  or no?

ps: I tried using

```
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, bestFPSRange);
```

with `bestFPSRange = [30,30]` , but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vishal , Were you able to fetch fixed frame rate?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use YUV420 to get data from ImageReader:-

```
ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth,mHeight ,ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, maxImages);
```

Also, check your mWidth and mHeight.

You can try the following approach to measure fps:-

```
int frameCount=0;
    long frameTime=0;
    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mImageAvailableRight=new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
            try{


                Object[] objects=initFPSNew("Measure fps is-->",frameTime,frameCount);
                frameTime=(long)objects[0];
                frameCount=(int)objects[1];

                Image mImage=imageReader.acquireNextImage();
                if(mImage!=null){
                    mImage.close();
                }

            }catch (Exception exc)
            {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                Log.v(TAG,"Exception Camera2"+ exc.getMessage());
            }

        }
    };





public static Object[] initFPSNew(String message,long startTime,int counter){

        Object[] mObjectTime=new Object[2];
        if(startTime==0){

            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            mObjectTime[0]=startTime;
            counter+=1;
            mObjectTime[1]=counter;
        }else{
            long difference=System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
            //We wil check count only after 1 second laps 
            double seconds = difference / 1000.0;

            if(seconds>=1)
            {
                Log.v(TAGFPS,message+ counter);
                counter=0;
                mObjectTime[0]=System.currentTimeMillis();
                mObjectTime[1]=counter;

            }else{
                counter++;
                mObjectTime[0]=startTime;
                mObjectTime[1]=counter;
            }

        }
        return mObjectTime;
    }
```